# Link between zipfian distribution and probability of accessing a single object

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to understand Zipf's law in more detail, and more specifically,
the relationship between:

1) a set of accesses to objects $\{A,B\}$ following a zipfian distribution over a number of repeated events $b$. A has rank $k=1$, and B has rank $k = 2$.

2) the probability of any single "access" being for $A$ and/or for $B$.

3) the binomial distribution of getting "$k$" successes, where a success can be respectively "accessing $A$" or "accessing $B$".

My solution will need to be generalised to $n$ objects, but for now I want to undertand the basic relationships between those three points. I know very little probability theory so don't have much of an intuition, could someone potentially explain?

Comment: I find your question quite unclear.  Zipf's distribution assigns a probability to each positive integer.  What does that have to do with your two "objects"?

Comment: Let A have rank k = 1, and B rank k = 2.

Comment: You're being altogether unclear.  How does a probability distribution supported on the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ get involved in this? ${}\qquad{}$